# Curl of PHP 7.0.30 not working on ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit)

Tags: curl, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, php-7

I am using ubuntu 14.04 on AWS Ec2 instance and recently i update the PHP version from 5.6 to 7.0.30 using command via ssh.

After updating my PHP, curl stop working.

I try uninstall it and re-install but getting the same error again and again

Are we unable to use the PHP 7.0.30 with Ubuntu 14.04

When I try to use curl I will get this error.

Error: **Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()**

If someone face this issue can you tell me how to resolve this .

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Comment: I don't think the php curl extension is included automatically. I believe you'll need to specifically install that extension.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the curl-extension for php. Either you find the php.ini on the server and enable the curl-extension within it (remove `;` in front of `extension=php_curl.dll`) or install via ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl`. Restart apache either way and you should be golden.

Comment: If we installed php the apt way, I'd firmly recommend installing php7.0-curl the apt way as well.

Comment: As would i. Since there is no specification how php was installed i gave both possible solutions.